# two-dimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

OK so here's my code:

```
$months = Array();

$months = ['January'=>array(), 'February'=>array(), 'March'=>array(), 'April'=>array(), 'May'=>array(), 'June'=>array(), 'July'=>array(), 'August'=>array(), 'September'=>array(), 
                        'October'=>array(), 'November'=>array(), 'December'=>array() ]; 
// Connect to MySQL
if ( !( $database = mysql_connect( "localhost", "root", "" ) ) )                      
      die( "Could not connect to database </body></html>" );

// open Events database
if ( !mysql_select_db( "Events", $database ) )
      die( "Could not open Events database </body></html>" );

for($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posted_events WHERE Month_ = '$months[$i]' ") 
                    or die ('Error updating database because: '.mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $months[$i] =  $row['DayNum']; 
    }


}
```

I don't know if you could get what I'm trying to do here but I'll explain anyway. I'm trying to access my database and store dates corresponding to their respective months and store them in an array, but it doesn't work :/

I'm new to this two-dimensional array thing, so I don't know if my syntax is wrong or what I want to achieve is impossible.
Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: As a side-note: avoid using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use `mysqli_*` instead.

Comment: The main problem here may be that your array key are strings and you're trying to access them by ints. If that's the issue, `array_keys` may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$months[$i] will end up as "Array" because it is an array

to get the month name you should put:

$month_names = array_keys($months);

after the $months variable

then use it

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posted_events WHERE Month_ = '$month_names[$i]' ")

cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Your months array is an associative array with strings as keys, so you can use `foreach` to iterate over it instead of an incremental `for`. Also remember to append to the array not overwrite it on each iteration.

```
foreach($months as $month => $arr) {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posted_events WHERE Month_ = '$month' ") 
                    or die ('Error updating database because: '.mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $months[$month][] =  $row['DayNum']; 
        //             ^^ appending not overwriting
    }
}
```

Side notes:

- `mysql_*` is deprecated, I suggest upgrading to PDO or MySQLi.
- The `or die` syntax is undesirable because it's hard to change it when you move to production. Something like `trigger_error()` would be better which silently writes to the error log.

Edit: to output the dates in the array:

```
foreach($months as $month => $arr)
{
    echo $month . '<br />';
    foreach($arr as $day)
    {
        echo $day . '<br />';
    }
}
```

The above will simply echo out the month name and then all of the dates below it, and repeat for the next month.

Comment: hey could you show me how i could output the dates stored in the array? Having a lil problem doing that